# Android app crashes on startup sometimes

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash

I have a problem with an Android app of mine.
Sometimes it crashes on startup, but sometimes it doesn't.
Sadly, LogCat did not help me, and I have no idea what is wrong.

My app uses an AsyncTask to fetch and process data from the Internet.

What could cause the problem?

Here is the LogCat log:

```
01-03 21:43:29.998: D/AbsListView(28500): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-03 21:43:30.008: D/ProgressBar(28500): setProgress = 0
01-03 21:43:30.008: D/ProgressBar(28500): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
01-03 21:43:30.008: D/ProgressBar(28500): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
01-03 21:43:30.038: D/AbsListView(28500): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-03 21:43:30.038: D/AbsListView(28500): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 21:43:30.038: D/AbsListView(28500): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-03 21:43:30.038: D/AbsListView(28500): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 21:43:30.179: D/libEGL(28500): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
01-03 21:43:30.189: D/libEGL(28500): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
01-03 21:43:30.189: D/libEGL(28500): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): Build Date: 09/26/13 Thu
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): Local Branch: 
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): Remote Branch: 
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): Local Patches: 
01-03 21:43:30.189: I/Adreno-EGL(28500): Reconstruct Branch: 
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/OpenGLRenderer(28500): Enabling debug mode 0
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/ProgressBar(28500): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/ProgressBar(28500): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/ProgressBar(28500): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/ProgressBar(28500): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
01-03 21:43:30.239: D/AbsListView(28500): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 21:43:30.249: D/AbsListView(28500): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-03 21:43:30.479: D/AndroidRuntime(28500): Shutting down VM
01-03 21:43:30.479: W/dalvikvm(28500): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c6898)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131427329, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class se.taby10.application.NewsList)]
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1557)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2444)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1247)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6355)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-03 21:43:30.489: E/AndroidRuntime(28500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 21:43:33.262: I/Process(28500): Sending signal. PID: 28500 SIG: 9
```

And the code:

```
package se.taby10.application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnWebsite, btnCourses;
    ListView newsList;
    ArrayList<Item> newsArrayList;
    ArrayAdapter<Item> newsAdapter;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    String feedUrl = "http://taby10.se/feed.php?encoding=json";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = this;
        newsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsList);
        settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        newsArrayList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        newsAdapter = new NewsList(MainActivity.this, newsArrayList);

        newsList.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
        newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Set up intent and pass item data
                Intent intent = new Intent("se.taby10.application.SINGLENEWS");

                intent.putExtra("ItemId", newsArrayList.get(position).getId());
                intent.putExtra("ItemTitle", newsArrayList.get(position)
                        .getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("ItemContent", newsArrayList.get(position)
                        .getContent());
                intent.putExtra("ItemTimestamp", newsArrayList.get(position)
                        .getTimestamp());
                intent.putExtra("ItemUrl", newsArrayList.get(position).getUrl());

                // Start activity to show news in
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Buttons
        btnWebsite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWebsite);
        btnWebsite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                websiteIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://taby10.se"));
                startActivity(websiteIntent);
            }
        });

        btnCourses = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCourses);
        btnCourses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent coursesIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                coursesIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://taby10.se/courses"));
                startActivity(coursesIntent);
            }
        });

        // Load feed
        NewsListTask loaderTask = new NewsListTask();
        loaderTask.execute();

        refresh();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_about:
            startActivity(new Intent("se.taby10.application.ABOUT"));
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent("se.taby10.application.SETTINGS"));
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        int updateFrequency = settings.getInt("updatefrequency", 600);

        if (updateFrequency != 0) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Reload news feed
                    NewsListTask loaderTask = new NewsListTask();
                    loaderTask.execute();

                    // Reset timer
                    refresh();
                }
            }, updateFrequency * 1000);
        }
    }

    public class NewsListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Hämtar nyheter");
            dialog.setMessage("Vänta medan nyheter laddas. Detta kan ta ett tag.");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(feedUrl);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                String jsonData = builder.toString();
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonData);

                // Get items from json
                for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

                    Item objItem = new Item();

                    objItem.setId(e.getInt("id"));
                    objItem.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(
                            Html.fromHtml(e.getString("title")).toString())
                            .toString());
                    objItem.setDescription(Html.fromHtml(
                            Html.fromHtml(e.getString("description"))
                                    .toString()).toString());
                    objItem.setContent(Html.fromHtml(
                            Html.fromHtml(e.getString("content")).toString())
                            .toString());
                    objItem.setTimestamp(Html
                            .fromHtml(e.getString("timestamp")).toString());
                    objItem.setUrl(Html.fromHtml(e.getString("link"))
                            .toString());

                    newsArrayList.add(objItem); // Add item to list
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131427329, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class se.taby10.application.NewsList)]

Comment: Are you by chance updating the `Adapter` for your `ListView` in `doInBackground()`?

Comment: It is called once from the onPostExecute() method on the AsyncTask. Could this be the problem, and is there a way to move it but just call it whenever the AsyncTask has been run?

Comment: Can you post the code you have inside `doInBackground()`?

Comment: Can you show your `AsyncTask`? Updating in `onPostExecute()` should be fine as it runs on the `UI Thread`

Comment: There, I have included the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have some sort of List that provides the data to your adapter?
if this is the case, you should not modify it in a different thread. You should fetch the data and when you have the new List, then pass it to the adapter and call the notifydatasetchanged method to update it.

The logcat says that you are changing the adapter's data without notifying!

Comment: This was indeed the problem. I solved it through the use of a temporary list, containing all the items, and then adding everything to the primary list using the function addAll();